# Cannot train a model with numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, deep-learning, autoencoder

I am training the following autoencoder on float numbers.

```
input_img = Input(shape=(2623,1), name='input')

x = ZeroPadding1D(1)(input_img)
x = Conv1D(32, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', use_bias=False)(input_img)
x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(x)
x = MaxPooling1D(2, padding='same')(x)
x = Conv1D(16, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', use_bias=False)(x)
x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(x)
x = MaxPooling1D(2, padding='same')(x)
x = Conv1D(16,3, activation='relu', padding='same', use_bias=False)(x)
x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(x)
encoded = MaxPooling1D(2, padding='same')(x)


x = Conv1D(16,3, activation='relu', padding='same', use_bias=False)(encoded)
x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(x)
x = UpSampling1D(2)(x)
x = Conv1D(16,3, activation='relu', padding='same', use_bias=False)(x)
x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(x)
x = UpSampling1D(2)(x)
x = Conv1D(32, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', use_bias=False)(x)  #input_shape=(30, 1))
x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(x)  
x = UpSampling1D(2)(x)
x = Cropping1D(cropping=(0, 1))(x) #Crop nothing from input but crop 1 element from the end
decoded = Conv1D(1, 3, activation='sigmoid', padding='same', use_bias=False)(x)  

autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy')


x = Input(shape=(16, 300), name="input")
h = x
h = Conv1D(filters=300, kernel_size=16,
             activation="relu", padding='same', name='Conv1')(h)
h = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=16, name='Maxpool1')(h)
```

I had to convert the data to a numpy array in order to process it but when the model starts training i get:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float:

This is happening because my training data looks like :

> train[0][1] # one number of training data

```
array(['0.001758873'], dtype=object)
```

What can i do in order to avoid the "dtype=object" in my training data, or maybe do i have to convert it to something else?
Thank you!

Comment: You to encode if it is categorical variable, if it is float variable convert to float  
x = x.astype(np.float)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, as a preprocessing step, you can typecast your object type array to a float array using something like:

```
# if float32 is the desired & appropriate datatype
train = train.astype(numpy.float32)
```